# How to write a custom special property binding in Angular?

Tags: angular

Angular has a feature as `special property binding`. for example we can use `[class.className]` or `[style.line-height.em]` syntax in the property like

```
<!-- isActive() returns true or false in order to set active class -->
<h1 class="leading" [class.active]="isActive()">Title</h1>

<!-- getColor() returns a valid color -->
<h1 [style.color]="getColor()">Title</h1>
<h1 [style.line-height.em]="'2'">Title</h1>
```

How can I write a custom special property binding?
for example `[my.custom1]` or `[my.custom2.custom3]` or ...

My question is about these `dots` How angular handle them?

Is it possible? Any sample?

Comment: Does it have to be `[my.custom1]`, or is it ok to write it like `[custom1]`? In that case, you can use `@Input() custom1` in your controller

Comment: No it is not, My question is about these `dots` for simple one (not special) I know how to write.

Comment: For all I know, you can use directives and directives with parameters https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding, but I've never hear about "dot" syntax in a directive

Comment: You could probably figure this out by looking at Angular source code. PS. Using a function call in `[class.active]="isActive()"` is probably not a great idea.

Comment: its not a property binding - its an attribute binding. ref: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings

why would you need that in a custom scenario?

Comment: @deezg, I am reading `Angular in Action`. In this book, We have a section `3.6.3 Special property bindings`. My question came from it. I have no idea yet this is just a question.

Comment: that syntax is mostly used to bind style, css class or some other attribute for DOM elements. as ref example shows `[attr.aria-label]`. Other than that, i don't see why would you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to rename your input. Consider that not as an object notation, but as a whole, exhaustive liste of properties.

```js
@Input('my.custom2') myCustom2: any;
@Input('my.custom3') myCustom3: any;
```

For an example, you can look at [`@angular/flex-layout`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/flex/flex/flex.ts), which uses this notation (go at line 65)

**EDIT** Angular isn't "dynamic", they rely on Javascript to get those attributes. This is built in the framework and it isn't exposed for you to use. Look at this :

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(el.attributes[0].name);
```

```html
<div class.myClass="true"></div>
```

As you can see, you can get the attributes this way. Angular doesn't provide a way to select attribute "dynamically". It just offers one or two custom attribute reading like `class` or `attr`, but that's all.

For instance, a quick search in github's Angular repo will confirm this on [this file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e0ed59e55f8740303fc93784548d81c2de210e7e/packages/compiler/src/render3/r3_template_transform.ts) (line 161), [this file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27bc7dcb43ec20d185b92986cba06cbc0329b58f/packages/compiler/src/render3/view/template.ts) (line 276), [this file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c95437f15df93e2ca735ebf015acb20be597bb6a/packages/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_parser.ts) (line 67), and probably much more (I only checked first 3 pages of the search result).

Comment: Your approach is static. based on my sample `[class.className]` Angular accepts dynamic `className` as a second part. I think They should have a solution for this.